# I can't get my app to display anything after I submit a form

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

Hi I have a web app using node, express, cors and body-parser. I want to submit the city name and get the api to fetch data for me. but when I enter a city and click submit nothing happens. the url changes from "http://localhost:3000" to "http://localhost:3000/?". Also in the chrome console network tab I get 200 code the first time but after that I get 304 status codes no matter how many times I click submit. Here's my files:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Travel App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="application/css" href="../styles/styles.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="form">
            <form id="userInfo">
                <label for="city">Enter city: </label>
                <input type="text" id="city">
                <button type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

        </div>
        <div class="data">
            <div class="lat"></div>
            <div class="lng"></div>
            <div class="country"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../index.js" type="application/json"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js:

```
const baseURL = "http://api.geonames.org/searchJSON";
const username = "sampleusername";

const userInfo = document.getElementById("userInfo");
const submitBtn = document.getElementById("submitBtn");

submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    const city = document.getElementById("city").value;

    if (city !== "") {
        getCountryInfo(baseURL, city, username)
            .then(function (info) {
                postData("/add", { lat: info.lat, lng: info.lng, country: info.country })
            }).then(function () {
                receiveData()
            }).catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert("City not found");
            });
        (userInfo.reset());

    }
    else {
        submitBtn.classList.add("invalid");
    }
})

const getCountryInfo = async (baseURL, city, username) => {
    const res = await fetch(`${baseURL}?q=${city}&username=${username}`);
    try {
        const info = await res.json();
        return info['geonames'][0];
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
};

const postData = async (url = "", data = {}) => {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        credentials: "same-origin",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            lat: data.lat,
            lng: data.lng,
            country: data.country
        })
    });
    try {
        const newData = await response.json();
        return newData;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const receiveData = async () => {
    const request = await fetch('/all');
    try {
        // Transform into JSON
        const allData = await request.json()
        // Write updated data to DOM elements
        document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML = allData.lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').innerHTML = allData.lng;
        document.getElementById("country").innerHTML = allData.country;
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
        // appropriately handle the error
    }
}
```

server.js:

```
// Setup empty JS object to act as endpoint for all routes
projectData = {};

// Require Express to run server and routes
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

// Start up an instance of app
const app = express();

/* Middleware*/
//Here we are configuring express to use body-parser as middle-ware.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Cors for cross origin allowance
app.use(cors())
// Initialize the main project folder
app.use(express.static('/src/client'));

app.get("/all", function sendData(req, res) {
    res.send(projectData);
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile("index.html", { root: "../client/views" })
})

app.post("/add", (req, res) => {
    projectData['lng'] = req.body.lng;
    projectData['lat'] = req.body.lat;
    projectData['country'] = req.body.country;
    res.send(projectData);
})

// Setup Server
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Travel App listening on port 3000")
    console.log("Go to http://localhost:3000")
})
```

Can someone duplicate this code and see what they get by running "node server.js"?

Comment: Your page reloads after submit because you didn't `preventDefault` and used `click` event instead of `submit`

Comment: I updated the code with your changes... but I still can't get any results back

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import a script directly, you should not use `application/json` as the type. `application/json` has another purpose.

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#embedding_data_in_html)

> You can also use the  element to embed data in HTML with server-side rendering by specifying a valid non-JavaScript MIME type in the type attribute.

Replace this line

```
<script src="../index.js" type="application/json"></script>
```

With

```
<script src="../index.js"></script>
```

Now the javascript will run and the server will respond to your requests.

---

#### EDIT

*"now there's an error on the console ... "refused to execute script from ... because its mime type ("text/html ") is not executable"*

The problem here is related to your file structure. It's about the path that the html file sent from the server is trying to reach the javascript file.

I will give an example.

```
project
|
|-- public
|     js
|       index.js
|     views
|       index.html
|
|-- server.js
```

server.js:

```
...
const path = require("path");
...
app.use(express.static("public"));
...
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/views/index.html"));
});
```

public/views/index.html:

```
<script src="/js/index.js"></script>
```

Now when it requests `localhost:3000`, the html and javascript file will load successfully.

But in this scenario, if you change your static path:

```
app.use(express.static("some-path"))
```

Request `localhost:3000` again, in the Chrome Console tab, you will see the error ***refused to execute script from ... because its mime type ("text/html ") is not executable***.

Or if you change the javascript path in the html file it will give the same error.

You can solve this error through the example I gave.

Comment: Hi now there's an error on the console ... "refused to execute script from ... because its mime type ("text/html ") is not executable

Comment: I edited my answer. If it doesn't work, please let me know.